# Crash dump analysis for multi threaded c++ application crash

Tags: c++, multithreading, windbg, dump

This is a question on generic scenario. I have a multi threaded c++ application which crashed and I have the crash dump. There might be hundreds of thread running and any of them might have caused the crash.

1. What would be the good approach to start analyzing the crash dump.
2. Among many threads (already logged information under dump file) how to find any specific thread causing the crash. Should I look for any specific criteria because I cannot go ahead and analyze all the threads and their stacks.
3. Any other useful information/clue you want to suggest.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: It shouldn't surprise you that for a situation like this, there is no paint-by-numbers recipe that works for all multi-threaded applications, everywhere. Each multi-threaded application is different, and works in different ways. Your debugger should tell you which thread crashed, and you go from there.

Comment: Multithreaded programs are some of the most difficult programs to debug.  That's why they pay MT programmers much more than single-thread programmers.  It is an art that requires a lot of experience.  The issue isn't just about analyzing threads -- you also have to know how to address the issue, which again, could be difficult to establish.  If you're only used to single-thread programmers with little to no experience with multi-thread programs, and then asked to debug such a program, you have an uphill battle.

Comment: `!analyze -v`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-the--analyze-extension

Comment: I have worked as a crash dump analyzer in the past, and our programs (Windows programs) all had `try ... catch` and `_TRY ... _EXCEPT` clauses for creating crash dumps of themselves, which allowed to see the exact thread that was crashed.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and valuable inputs.

Answer (score 2):

We call the following code a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and you should provide it as part of your question in the future.

It creates 100 threads, synchronizes them so that they all start running at the same time (needs C++ 20). One of the threads will generate an exception randomly, so that we don't know which one it was.

```
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 twister(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 100);
std::counting_semaphore<100> synchronizer(0);

void randomCrash()
{
    synchronizer.acquire();
    if (dist(twister) < 2)
    {
        throw std::exception();
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms); // Ensure the thread is still there when we analyze the dump
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        std::thread t(&randomCrash);
        threads.push_back(std::move(t)); // Threads can't be copied, so move it
    }
    std::cout << "Created 100 threads.\r\n";
    
    synchronizer.release(100);
    std::cout << "100 threads running now.\r\n";
    
    for (std::thread& th : threads)
    {
        if (th.joinable())
        {
            th.join();
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Done. Ooops ... no exception happened? Well, that's randomness.\r\n";
}
```

If we now open the crash dump, we can see that it has already switched to thread 92 which caused the exception by looking at the prompt:

```
0:092>
```

But let's pretend that didn't work by using the command `~0s`, so we're back on the main thread.

```
0:092> ~0s
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14:
00007ffc`cbcacc94 c3              ret
0:000>
```

Using the `~` command, you can identify the thread(s) which caused an exception:

```
0:000> ~
.  0  Id: 3edc.cc8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 0000004a`fb029000 Unfrozen
[...]
  91  Id: 3edc.38d0 Suspend: 1 Teb: 0000004a`fb0df000 Unfrozen
# 92  Id: 3edc.2418 Suspend: 1 Teb: 0000004a`fb0e1000 Unfrozen
  93  Id: 3edc.4788 Suspend: 1 Teb: 0000004a`fb0e3000 Unfrozen
[...]
 103  Id: 3edc.43e4 Suspend: 1 Teb: 0000004a`fb0f7000 Unfrozen
```

The current thread has a dot (`.`) and the threads with an exception have a hash (`#`). Note that the dot may hide the hash if the current thread is the one which threw the exception. So you can easily switch to the thread

```
0:000> ~92s
ucrtbase!abort+0x4e:
00007ffc`c960286e cd29            int     29h
```

and look at the call stack

```
0:092> k
 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 0000004a`80efe500 00007ffc`c9601f9f     ucrtbase!abort+0x4e
01 0000004a`80efe530 00007ffc`b6e01aab     ucrtbase!terminate+0x1f
02 0000004a`80efe560 00007ffc`b6e02317     VCRUNTIME140_1!FindHandler<__FrameHandler4>+0x45b [D:\...\frame.cpp @ 693] 
03 0000004a`80efe730 00007ffc`b6e040d9     VCRUNTIME140_1!__InternalCxxFrameHandler<__FrameHandler4>+0x267 [D:\...\frame.cpp @ 357] 
04 0000004a`80efe7d0 00007ffc`cbcb1f6f     VCRUNTIME140_1!__CxxFrameHandler4+0xa9 [D:\...\risctrnsctrl.cpp @ 306] 
05 0000004a`80efe840 00007ffc`cbc61454     ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0xf
06 0000004a`80efe870 00007ffc`cbcb0a9e     ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x244
07 0000004a`80efef80 00007ffc`c96bd759     ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+0x2e
08 0000004a`80eff6b0 00007ffc`a9f36480     KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69
09 0000004a`80eff790 00007ff7`49ec13fd     VCRUNTIME140!_CxxThrowException+0x90 [D:\...\throw.cpp @ 75] 
0a 0000004a`80eff7f0 00007ff7`49ec1ecb     WhichThreadCrashes!randomCrash+0x1bd [C:\...\WhichThreadCrashes.cpp @ 19] 
0b (Inline Function) --------`--------     WhichThreadCrashes!std::invoke+0x2 [C:\...\type_traits @ 1585] 
0c 0000004a`80eff850 00007ffc`c95b1bb2     WhichThreadCrashes!std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl*)(void)>,0>+0xb [C:\...\thread @ 55] 
0d 0000004a`80eff880 00007ffc`cb7c7034     ucrtbase!thread_start<unsigned int (__cdecl*)(void *),1>+0x42
0e 0000004a`80eff8b0 00007ffc`cbc62651     kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
0f 0000004a`80eff8e0 00000000`00000000     ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

So we can see it crashes in `randomCrash()`.

Once you know how it works, you can also switch to the thread with the exception directly by using `~#s`:

```
0:092> ~0s
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14:
00007ffc`cbcacc94 c3              ret
0:000> ~#s
ucrtbase!abort+0x4e:
00007ffc`c960286e cd29            int     29h
0:092>
```

Also, `!analyze -v` should give you

```
0:000> !analyze -v
[...]
STACK_COMMAND:  ~92s ; .ecxr ; kb
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and valuable inputs. This will help.